# Why is my virtual function not assigning values?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

I am trying to use a virtual function to calculate area of rectangle and triangle like this:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape{
   public:
   int width;
   int height;
   void get(){
       cin>>width;
       cin>>height;
   }

   virtual void area(){
       cout<<"Calculates area";
   }
};

class Triangle:public Shape{

  void area(){
      int a = height*width/2;
      cout<<a<<endl;
  }
};

class Rectangle:public Shape{

  void area(){
      int a = height*width;
      cout<<a<<endl;
  }
};





int main(){
    Shape shapeObj;
    shapeObj.get();

    Shape *ptr;
    Triangle trObj;
    Rectangle rectObj;

    ptr=&trObj;
    ptr->area();

    ptr=&rectObj;
    ptr->area();
}
```

But my program is returning 0 as the area of both shapes. I think the value of width and height is not assigned in the Triangle and Rectangle class.Can someone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book then the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)...). See also some good [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Consider using [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Be aware of the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html). Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler, with GCC use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Yes, this mistake is fundamental and it should be answered by any C++ tutorial. In addition, learning how to step through code with a debugger would be a useful thing to learn and could help you solve this yourself. In case you haven't, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Leaving the `main` function aside for which you already got an answer by @john, your `area()` functions in the derived classes `Rectangle` and `Triangle` should be public. Default for `class` is `private`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the width and height are assigned to the `shapeObj` variable

```
Shape shapeObj;
shapeObj.get();
```

but you are using the `trObj` and `rectObj` variables to calculate the area.

```
Triangle trObj;
Rectangle rectObj;
ptr=&trObj;
ptr->area();
ptr=&rectObj;
ptr->area();
```

Try this instead

```
int main()
{
    Triangle trObj;
    trObj.get();
    Shape* ptr=&trObj;
    ptr->area();

    Rectangle rectObj;
    rectObj.get();
    ptr=&rectObj;
    ptr->area();
}
```

Of course because you have two variables and are calling `get` twice then this code is going to ask for the width and height twice. If that is not what you want then think carefully about how you are doing the I/O in this program, and how it could be designed better (hint: do the I/O in main and use parameters and return values in your classes).